# Encode MIME multipart with binary data in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mime

How can I construct a MIME multipart message in Python? I've tried the `email` package of Python but it appears broken -- it doesn't properly do binary sections (sets their `Content-Transfer-Encoding` to base64 and leaves the data as binary). Note it is very important the actual data is binary encoded, and not base64, for my application. I need to minimize the size.

This is the code I tried.

```
from email import message, mime, generator, encoders
from email.mime import multipart, text, image
from cStringIO import StringIO
import os

m = multipart.MIMEMultipart( "related" )

part = text.MIMEText( "text", "plain" )
part.set_payload( "hello" )
part.add_header( 'Content-Disposition', 'asset', name='abc' )
m.attach( part )

part = image.MIMEImage( "image", "x-other" )
part.set_payload( os.urandom(200) )
m.attach( part )

fp = StringIO()
g = generator.Generator( fp, mangle_from_ = False, maxheaderlen = 1000 )
g.flatten(m)
print( fp.getvalue() )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force whichever `Content-Transfer-Encoding` you want like this:

```
part = image.MIMEImage( "image", "x-other", encoders.encode_noop )
part.set_payload( os.urandom(200) )
part.add_header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary' )
m.attach( part )
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It just adds a second header and leaves the broken `base64` one in place.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y It does work for me on Python 2.7.3. Have you noted the `encoders.encode_noop`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that part. Yes doing that I can get binary encoding. I'm concerned though that since "binary" isn't a standard encoder that perhaps it can't decode these messages.

Comment: Okay, this works. Python doesn't really support this encoding though, it just silently does not decode it.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y What do you mean by “does not decode”? By definition, the `binary` encoding does not require any decoding to get to the original octets.

Comment: The Python decoder ignores encodings it doesn't understand and returns the raw payload. This only accidentally works for binary encoding. If there is some other encoding there it doesn't understand I'll silently get garbage back. :(

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem...